# Generate PDF in ZF2?

Tags: php, pdf, zend-framework2, dompdf

I'm starting a new project, and I am also fairly new to Zend Framework 2. 
What are your suggestions to generate a pdf from an html code that you want to pass as a variable ($html)? 
I was reading the web that DOMPDF is pretty good, but I'm not sure how to use it, looking at documentation. 
What would be the easiest way for a beginner?

Comment: http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php - generates pdf from html. If you are alerady familiar to css and html that library is quite easy to start. Also it has good documentation and rich features.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your selection of DOMPDF is right. It's the most easiest to use in Zend Framework 2. Just add a simple module(DOMPDFModule) and you are ready to go. As you are a newbie to Zend Framework 2; here is how to use it.

### Step 1: Downloading DOMPDFModule

Add **"dino/dompdf-module": "dev-master"** to the **require** section in **composer.json** file
**Example:**
*composer.json*

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "zendframework/zendframework": "2.2.*",
    "dino/dompdf-module": "dev-master"
}
```

Now **install** or **update** the dependencies using **composer**. Composer will automatically include the dependencies which we would otherwise include using *include("dompdf.php")*
**Example:**

```
php composer.phar install
```

Next we have to add **DOMPDFModule** to the **modules** section in **config/application.config.php**
**Example:**
*application.config.php*

```
'modules' => array(
    'Application',
    'DOMPDFModule',
),
```

And we are ready to use it in our project.

### Step 2: Using it in Zend Framework 2 Project

Open up the controller in which we are going to generate the PDF and add
**use DOMPDFModule\View\Model\PdfModel;**
to the top; after the namespace.
**Example:**
*IndexController.php*

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use DOMPDFModule\View\Model\PdfModel;
```

Next we have to place the necessary PDF generation code to the required action.
**Example:**
I'm assuming; to download pdf we are using the following route.
**example.com/generatepdf**

For that create a **generatepdfAction()** method in which we will place the PDF generation logic as follows.
*IndexController.php*

```
public function generatepdfAction()
{
    $pdf = new PdfModel();
    return $pdf;
}
```

As most **Action** in Zend Framework 2; this action will also have a corresponding view file **generatepdf.phtml** where we actually place the HTML which is to be converted to PDF.
**Example:**
*generatepdf.phtml*

```
<html>
  <body>
      <h1>My Name is Blah</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now if we go to the route we created; a PDF will be shown in the same window if the browser supports viewing PDF.

### Passing variables to view file

It can be done in **generatepdfAction()** by using the **setVariables()** method of **PdfModel()**
**Example:**
*IndexController.php*

```
public function generatepdfAction()
{
    $pdf = new PdfModel();
    $pdf->setVariables(array(
      'name' => 'John Doe',
    ));
    return $pdf;
}
```

*generatepdf.phtml*

```
<html>
  <body>
      <h1>My Name is <?php echo $this->name; ?></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Setting filename and forcing download

Setting filename will trigger auto download of the PDF file. A filename can be set using the **setOption()** method of **PdfModel()**.
**Example:**
*IndexController.php*

```
public function generatepdfAction()
{
    $pdf = new PdfModel();
    $pdf->setOption("filename", "my-file");
    return $pdf;
}
```

File extension(.pdf) will be added automatically.

### Setting paper size and paper orientation

Paper size and paper orientation can be set by the **paperSize** and **paperOrientation** options
**Example:**
*IndexController.php*

```
public function generatepdfAction()
{
    $pdf = new PdfModel();
    $pdf->setOption("paperSize", "a4"); //Defaults to 8x11
    $pdf->setOption("paperOrientation", "landscape"); //Defaults to portrait
    return $pdf;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Finny! I'll try this and write about it.

Comment: This answer is the best "beginner friendly" for generate a pdf with ZF2. Thanks a lot Funny! Works great!!

Comment: :) Glad that it helps. Most developers in core PHP who are newbie to Zend Framework 2 have a confusion on how to use DOMPDF. So thought to post the answer in a beginner friendly way. If it suits the purpose you mentioned in the question; do accept it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: +1 for the details. It's noteworthy though that the generated PDF is not cached / stored anywhere. It's just a direct file output.

Comment: This is just a perfect answer. You got to love Stackoverflow for this! Thanks a ton! This should actually be part of the readme of the github repo!

Comment: this is great, after suffering trying to use another PDF library in zf2 this is just what I need. Thanks Finny!

Comment: Thanks for writing in detail, which really help me. Now I was to download and send the generated pdf file in the mail. How can I do that?

Comment: +1, however, you must use `php` in `generatepdf.phtml` to display variables. So you must update your code to `<html>
  <body>
      <h1>My Name is <?php echo $this->name; ?> </h1>
  </body>
</html>`

Comment: @FopaLéonConstantin - Thanks for pointing it. Have updated it in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at: http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php

It generates pdf from html. If you are alerady familiar with css and html that library is quite easy to start. Also it has good documentation and rich features.

Getting started borrowed from their documentation:

```
include('../mpdf.php');

// Create an instance of the class:
$mpdf=new mPDF();

// Write some HTML code:
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<p>Hello World</p>');

// Output a PDF file:
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
```

[Manual](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php)

[Generated files examples page](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php?page=Examples)

Comment: Keep in mind, that the above code is framework-independent, and all you really need to use this is to install it and to include it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use DOMPDF, there is a module, [DOMPDFModule](https://github.com/raykolbe/DOMPDFModule) for Zend Framework 2 which makes pdf generation a piece of cake.

```
<?php

namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use DOMPDFModule\View\Model\PdfModel;

class ReportController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function monthlyReportPdfAction()
    {
        $pdf = new PdfModel();
        $pdf->setOption('filename', 'monthly-report'); // Triggers PDF download, automatically appends ".pdf"
        $pdf->setOption('paperSize', 'a4'); // Defaults to "8x11"
        $pdf->setOption('paperOrientation', 'landscape'); // Defaults to "portrait"

        // To set view variables
        $pdf->setVariables(array(
          'message' => 'Hello'
        ));

        return $pdf;
    }
}
```

### Alternatives

You can use [Snappy](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy) which uses [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) for PDF generation from a url or a html page. For Zend Framework 2, there is a module [MvlabsSnappy](https://github.com/mvlabs/MvlabsSnappy).

Comment: DOMPDFModule module does not work with Zend Framework 3. Can you suggest me any alternative of this module which can be installed in Zend Framework 3?

Comment: that module seems unmaintained at this moment of time. so, I can't see the module creator porting it to support zf3 any time soon. But, you can always create an issue to find out. If you want an easy for now, you can create the pdf response yourself in the controller using the dompdf library by taking ideas from the same module. Checkout [PdfStrategy](https://github.com/raykolbe/DOMPDFModule/blob/ebb367877e25a39e597b529abd25f5390422253b/src/DOMPDFModule/View/Strategy/PdfStrategy.php#L102) and DOMPDFModule\View\Renderer\PdfRenderer::render

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I will try to find out something.